# Divide By Zero Message remains when changing the second text box

Tags: c#

Calculator project that has 2 Textboxes for number entry, a drop-down list, "OperatorList", for math operator, and a Calculate button.

The Goal: When the user enters in the values into the text boxes and selects the math operator it displays the results in a "Results" label. If the user attempts to divide by zero a message is display in the Result label "You cannot divide by zero, otherwise perform the "/" operation.

The message does display on the "Result Label" stating "You cannot divide by zero" when the "/" is in the OperatorList and a 0 is in the value2 textbox. However, if I change the second number the message "You cannot divide by zero" remains and the math "/" isn't executed. My C# code is below but the message won't display. I'm new to C# so I know I'm missing or overlooking something simple, Please help.

```
if (ValueBox1.Text.Length > 0 && ValueBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    switch (OperatorList.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "+":
            result = value1 + value2;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = value1 - value2;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = value1 * value2;
            break;
    }

    if (OperatorList.SelectedValue == "/")
    {
        if (value2 == 0)
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = "You cannot divide by zero";
        }
        result = value1 / value2;

        return;
    }

    ResultLabel.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How are you getting `value1` and `value2` from the textboxes and when? Also, when this piece of code is getting called?

Comment: Whenever you select `/` you are returning before setting the Text

Comment: They are variables set within the "Calculate" Button the user clicks after entering in values and selecting the math operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating this piece of code, I moved the return statement. This forces your divide operation to not reach the display section at the bottom of your code.

```
        if (OperatorList.SelectedValue == "/")
        {
            if (value2 == 0)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = "You cannot divide by zero";
                return;
            }                
            result = value1 / value2;
        }            
        ResultLabel.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank You Allan, I moved the "return" around a few times but never there. Thank you!!!

Comment: But the exception is happening in the `switch` statement before this code, right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to test for zero divide before you do the divide. You are doing the test afterwards

```
           switch (OperatorList.SelectedValue)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = value1 + value2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = value1 - value2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = value1 * value2;
                    break;
                case "/":                   
                    if (value2 == 0)
                    {
                       ResultLabel.Text = "You cannot divide by zero";
                       return;
                     }
                    result = value1 / value2;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Exactly, I had given my answer but `PM` got late by 22 seconds to `pm100` :) So removed mine.